# Backup mails from Outlook 2010

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have my school email (Zimbra) which I access through IMAP server on Outlook 2010.

I am graduating from my school soon and then my school will shut down the service. I am looking for a way to backup my email on my computer and I also want a copy to be available as long as they provide me the service.

I read [an article](http://kb.fastmetrics.com/index.php/email/173-archivingemailoutlook2010/) which says using auto-archive will delete the mails on the server. Someone else said use offline mode, and I am not sure how it works.

Can anyone suggest me a nice way for incremental backup of my email on my computer while leaving a copy on the server itself?

Comment: Can you access your school's email through POP3 and simply download all the files then upload them to say a Google Mail account through the protical. If you want just create a local archive file and COPY AND PASTE the emails into the new "local" archive. Of course I would simply download all the files before the account is closed.

Comment: I thought about that. Accessing through POP3 is an option if I don't find anything at all. Or I can forward my mails to GMAIL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that since you have IMAP available - download thunderbird and configure it for IMAP.

When you have done this, install [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) which allows you to export a thunderbird mailbox into various formats.  This should give you what you need.